# Error in dbt compile with a local package

Tags: dbt

We are setting up a new dbt project which will probably have several engineers working on it.  To reduce merge conflicts I'm playing with creating "sub" projects per data subject area and then referencing those as local or git packages in a master project that runs the whole pipeline.

I created one simple "sub" project with some models and schema tests and referenced this as a local package in a master project.  dbt deps installed it ok, but when I run "dbt compile" I get an error like the below, does anyone have any ideas please?  dbt version 0.19.0 running on ubuntu 18.04 against a snowflake target

```
Runtime Error
  Compilation Error in test not_model_column_one (models/package_name/package_metadata.yml)
    'test_not' is undefined
```

Comment: It seems like there might be a syntax error in `models/package_name/package_metadata.yml` — could you include the contents of this file in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a simple typo, how embarassing. Somehow when I was moving files around into sub-projects an underscore got removed from "not_null" in one of my metadata files.  The project previously worked fine so not sure how it happened, must have been fat fingers.